# How to get name of process in background process with powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

As question how to get name of process in background process with powershell script?
How to find whether inside background process of the task manager can find the certain app name or not?
For example in the image below, i need to check whether have this item in background process "NetOp 32 Host Application. (32 bit)"

[image]

Comment: `Get-Process -DisplayName *NetOp*`

Comment: get this error message: Get-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DisplayName'

Comment: Sorry, it's `-Name` (I was thinking of a different cmdlet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task Manager shows FileDescription. You can game the same like that:

```
Get-Process | select @{Name='Name'; Expression={$_.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription}}
```

It is possible to filter the result:

```
Get-Process | select @{Name='Name'; Expression={$_.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription}} |? Name -match 'Visual'
```

My filtered results looks like:

```
Name
----
Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Preview
Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Preview
```

To check how many results you have, you can use `Count` property:

```
$filteredResults = Get-Process | select @{Name='Name'; Expression={$_.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription}} |? Name -match 'Visual'
$filteredResults.Count
```

Comment: Your way works! Thanks.
Then how to check whether can found specific name or not?

Comment: Hi fdafadf, do you know how to maximize the apps after I get the name from your code? The reason is because I rearize the apps only can show stop or running if maximize it

Comment: You have to use Windows Native Functions. There is good article about it https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/

Comment: I made an example which looking for Paint process, brings window to front and maximizes it. https://justpaste.it/1zcn0